# Exporting SSL Certificate in Linux Browser (or Linux Command Line) for Java Certificate Truststore

Tags: java, ssl, coldfusion-9, keytool, truststore

**Background:**

I am having some trouble consuming a Web Service with ColdFusion 9 (peer not authenticated).

First, I'm going to try [importing the cert into ColdFusion's underlying Java keystore](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html). If that doesn't work, I'm going to try to [fiddle with ColdFusion's security provider](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/1/12/Diagnosing-a-CFHTTP-issue--peer-not-authenticated).

But my questions are more specific...

**Question:**

How do I export the cert (at the right level) in Chrome (or Linux CLI), and in which format?

**Details**

I have seen some instructions for exporting a cert from a browser, but they have been for IE (old versions, at that), and I would prefer to use Chrome, because I'm on Linux.

In order to get to the screen shot, below, I:

- Click the lock icon next to the URL
- "Connection" tab (shows "The identity of this website has been verified by Thawte SSL CA")
- Click "Certificate Information Link"
- "Details" tab

[image: Screen Shot of Chrome's Certificate Export Dialog]

From there, I am able to export at one of four levels:

- Builtin Object Token:Thawte Premium Server CA
- thawte Primary Root CA
- Thawte SSL CA
- sb1.geolearning.com

Which one is appropriate?

Also, [Adobe's documentation](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html) says "The certificate must be an X.509 certificate in Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER) format.", and Chrome's export dialog offers these options:

- Base64-encoded ASCII, single certificate
- Base64-encoded ASCII, certificate chain
- DER-encoded binary, single certificate
- PKCS #7, single certificate
- PKCS #7, certificate chain
- All Files

I assume "DER-encoded binary, single certificate" is appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With a Browser

The following generated a certificate that I was able to import using keytool:

- Level: sb1.geolearning.com
- File Type: DER-encoded binary, single certificate

For posterity, here was the command used to import:

```
sudo keytool -import -keystore /opt/jrun4/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias "sb1.geolearning.com (Thawte SSL CA)" -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -file ~/Downloads/sb1.geolearning.com
```

---

## Without a Browser

Here's what I'm doing these days (in a Vagrant provisioner). In this script, the keystore is hard-coded, because I'm only using it for Lucee, at the moment; however, the path the the keystore could easily be parameterized. Also, the `runfile` related code is just so Vagrant doesn't run the script more than once; those lines are superfluous if you're not using the code as a Vagrant provisioner.

The only thing that really differentiates this from the above solution is that this gets the cert via `openssl s_client` (and cleans it up with `sed`) instead doing so manually, via a browser.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

description="Add cert to Lucee's keystore."

while :
do
    case $1 in
        --provisioned-dir=*)
            provisioned_dir=${1#*=}        # Delete everything up till "="
            shift
            ;;
        --runfile-name=*)
            runfile_name=${1#*=}        # Delete everything up till "="
            shift
            ;;
        --site-host-name=*)
            site_host_name=${1#*=}        # Delete everything up till "="
            shift
            ;;
        -*)
            echo "WARN: Unknown option (ignored): $1" >&2
            shift
            ;;
        *)  # no more options. Stop while loop
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

runfile="${provisioned_dir}/${runfile_name}"

if [ -f "${runfile}" ]; then
  echo "${description}: Already run."
  exit 0
fi

echo "add cert to keystore"

echo -n | \
  openssl s_client -connect ${site_host_name}:443 \
  | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' \
  > /tmp/${site_host_name}.cert

/opt/lucee/jdk/jre/bin/keytool \
  -import \
  -keystore /opt/lucee/lib/lucee-server/context/security/cacerts \
  -alias "${site_host_name} (self-signed)" \
  -storepass changeit \
  -file /tmp/${site_host_name}.cert \
  -noprompt \
  || true

touch "${runfile}"
```