# COM.Allaire.ColdFusion.HTTPFailure

Tags: coldfusion, get, try-catch, cfhttp, coldfusion-7

I'm working on a web app that is ran nightly to retrieve a large XML file from another server. We're using ColdFusion MX7. We run a CFHTTP GET with username, pass, and url. Then we write the field with a cffileaction write to our temp location. So that it can be parsed and sorted into a database. There are a few CFHTTP calls on the page cut one of them is failing. In the CFCatch I have the system email me the catch type and the message and I'm getting this.

- COM.Allaire.ColdFusion.HTTPFailure
- Connection Failure: Status code unavailable

This the call an write action as is (the credentials are right):

```
    <cfhttp method="GET" 
    username="#uname#" 
    password="#pw#" 
    url="#url#"
    resolveurl="yes"
    throwonerror="yes">
    </cfhttp>   

    <cffile action="write" file="#getdirectoryfrompath(GetCurrentTemplatePath())#\XML_FileName.xml" output="#cfhttp.fileContent#">
```

Is anyone familiar with his error?

Comment: Did you search for the error message? Here's a [SO post mentioning it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390369/cfhttp-over-ssl/16367194#16367194) and [here's a cf-talk one](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:48687). They both refer to SSL certificates...

Comment: We grabbed their certificate again, and rebooted our server and no luck. (Also, yes, I did Google the message. I'd be insulted but I've met the type of people who need that question asked of them). Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out we were getting the Cert from the other groups 'test' server and then trying to using to get things from their production server. So Peter was right! If you run into this problem check out these links:

[CFHTTP Over SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390369/cfhttp-over-ssl/16367194#16367194)

http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:48687

Comment: The second link is 404'd now. See here: https://web.archive.org/web/20141229213330/http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:48687